# How to get mustache html in java

Tags: java, mustache

I'm trying to use mustache to fill an html for me, then i want to get that html and use it as String.

A template like this -> template.xhtml

```
<table style="width:10%" align="center">
    <tr>
        <th>Old</th>
        <th>New</th>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>{{old}}</td>
        <td>{{new}}</td>                                
    </tr>
</table>
```

With a Hash like this:

```
HashMap<String, String> scopes = new HashMap<String, String>();
    scopes.put("old", "Testing");
    scopes.put("new", "Mustache");
```

Now how do i tell, Mustache to use template.xhtml and fill with scopes and then return me the html?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
String aux = "";    
MustacheFactory mf = new DefaultMustacheFactory();
    Mustache mustache = mf.compile("path/to/file.html");
    StringWriter stringWriter = new StringWriter();
    mustache.execute(stringWriter, wrapper);
    aux = stringWriter.toString();
    System.out.println(aux);
```

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at the very bottom of the Mustache project's readme file (https://github.com/spullara/mustache.java#readme). There's an example `main` method there that does almost exactly what you need. Just use a `StringWriter` instead of an `OutputStreamWriter` so that you can get the resulting HTML as a `String`.

Comment: @bacoco It looks like your `scopes` map has a problem -- in a `HashMap` you can't have multiple keys with the same name. So first you insert `Testing` under the `old` key, and then you replace that by inserting `Old` under the `old` key. Also, the map doesn't contain the `list` entry that the template expects, so Mustache simply skips that section and doesn't even try to read the `new` and `old` keys.

Answer (score 1):

I am using the spring starter mustache.

```
      <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-mustache</artifactId>
            <version>2.1.6.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>
```

```
MustacheResourceTemplateLoader loader = new MustacheResourceTemplateLoader("emailTemplates/", ".html");   // Inside resources emailTemplates dir

        Reader reader = loader.getTemplate("index");
        Template tmpl = Mustache.compiler().compile(reader);
// Template String "One, two, {{three}}. Three sir!"
        Map<String, String> data = new HashMap<String, String>();
        data.put("three", "six");
```

I hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

I face the same question in Android, i parse the html to String like that :

```
 public static String readInputStreamAsString(InputStream in)
        throws IOException {

    BufferedInputStream bis = new BufferedInputStream(in);
    ByteArrayOutputStream buf = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
    int result = bis.read();
    while(result != -1) {
        byte b = (byte)result;
        buf.write(b);
        result = bis.read();
        buf.flush();
    }
    return buf.toString();
}
```

fill the template in data :

```
  Map<String, String> data = new HashMap<>();
  data.put("data", "123");
  data.put("read_mode","day");
  data.put("font_size","small");
  Template tmpl = Mustache.compiler().compile(readInputStreamAsString(***InputStream)));
  String html = tmpl.execute(data);
```

It' works fine.